# __attribute__((malloc)) vs restrict

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, restrict

Why does gcc need `__attribute__((__malloc__))`? Shouldn't the same info be communicatable by declaring `malloc` (and similar functions) as returning `restrict`ed pointers (`void *restrict malloc(size_t)`)?

It seems to be that that approach would be better as apart from not requiring a nonstandard feature it would also allow one to apply it to functions "returning" via a pointer (`int malloc_by_arg(void *restrict*retval, size_t size);`).

Comment: Isn't it simply because the format of malloc is specified by the standard to be `void *malloc(size_t size);`? gcc isn't allowed to change the format of the function, or it would not be compliant and just as non-standard as some "attribute".

Comment: @Lundin True, although the standard could have specified `malloc` as one of two options (with and without `restrict`). Since some conforming compilers already treat the pointer returned by `malloc` as unaliased, it seems to me that it wouldn't be a breaking change if the standard one day started allowing the alternative declaration. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Yeah the returned pointer is by definition not aliased, since it has no "effective type". I suppose this can be regarded as a language defect; there's no reason why they shouldn't `restrict` qualify the returned pointer.

Comment: Relevant: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/1999-09n/msg00252.html

Answer (score 1):

Even being quite similar, same function yields different optimization when `restrict` or `__attribute__((malloc))` are added. Considering this example (included [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_12.1.0/com.ibm.xlc121.aix.doc/language_ref/fn_attrib_malloc.html) as a reference of a good example of `__attribute__((malloc))`):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
void* my_malloc(int size)  __attribute__ ((__malloc__))
{
    void* p = malloc(size);  
    if (!p) {    
        printf("my_malloc: out of memory!\n");    
        exit(1);  
}  
return p;
}

int main() {  
    int* x = &a;  
    int* p = (int*) my_malloc(sizeof(int));  
    *x = 0; 
    *p = 1;  
    if (*x) printf("This printf statement to be detected as unreachable 
              and discarded during compilation process\n");  
    return 0;
}
```

And this one (Same code without attributes):

```
void* my_malloc(int size);

int a;
void* my_malloc(int size)
{
    void* p = malloc(size);  
    if (!p) {    
        printf("my_malloc: out of memory!\n");    
        exit(1);  
    }  
    return p;
}
int main() {  
    int* x = &a;  
    int* p = (int*) my_malloc(sizeof(int));  
    *x = 0; 
    *p = 1;  
    if (*x) printf("This printf statement to be detected as unreachable 
        and discarded during compilation process\n");  
    return 0;
}
```

As we could expect, the code with the malloc attribute is better optimized (both with `-O3`) than without it. Let me include just the differences:

without attribute:

```
[...]
    call    ___main
    movl    $4, (%esp)
    call    _malloc
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  L9
    movl    $0, _a
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_remember_state
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
L9:
    .cfi_restore_state
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    movl    $1, (%esp)
    call    _exit
    .cfi_endproc
[...]
```

with attribute:

```
[...]
    call    ___main
    movl    $4, (%esp)
    call    _my_malloc
    movl    $0, _a
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
[...]
```

Nonetheless, the use of `restrict` in that case is worthless, given that it doesn't optimize the generated code.If we modify the original code to be used with `restrict` :

```
void *restrict my_malloc(int size);

int a;
void *restrict my_malloc(int size)
{
    void *restrict p = malloc(size);  
    if (!p) {    
    printf("my_malloc: out of memory!\n");    
    exit(1);  
}  
return p;
}
int main() {  
    int* x = &a;  
    int* p = (int*) my_malloc(sizeof(int));  
    *x = 0; 
    *p = 1;  
    if (*x) printf("This printf statement to be detected as unreachable and discarded \
        during compilation process\n");  
    return 0;
}
```

The asm code is exactly the same than the generated without the malloc attribute:

```
    [...]
    call    ___main
    movl    $4, (%esp)
    call    _malloc
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  L9
    movl    $0, _a
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_remember_state
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
L9:
    .cfi_restore_state
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    movl    $1, (%esp)
    call    _exit
    .cfi_endproc
[...]
```

So for malloc/calloc-like functions, the use of `__attribute__((__malloc__))` looks like more useful than `restrict`.

`__attribute__((__malloc__))` and `restrict` have different behaviours to optimize the code, even being their definitions quite similar. That makes me think that there is no point to "merge" them, given that the compiler achieves different optimizations through different ways. Even when both are used at the same tiem, the generated code won't be more optimized than the most optimizated code with just one of them (`__attribute__((__malloc__))` or `restrict`, depending on case). So is the programmer's choice to know which one fits better according to his/her code.

Why `__attribute__((__malloc__))` is not standard?  I don't know, but IMO, these similarities from the definition point of view, and differences from the behaviour point of view don't help to integrate both in the standard, with a clear, well differentiated and general speaking way.

Comment: While your answer is correct, I think it doesn't answer the essence of the question: why can't the optimizations achieved via `__attribute__((__malloc__))` be achieved via `restrict`, considering that `restrict` is a standard way to mark unaliased pointers, such as those returned by allocators?

Comment: I see your point, my answer was more focused on trying to show the differences. I have edited my answer to add a clearer conclusion, even if it is not useful at all.

Comment: I think your answer clearly shows a GCC bug (or an optimization miss)

Comment: It's weird: I can't seem to compile the IBM example: `malloc.c:4:1: error: attributes should be specified before the declarator in a function definition`.  I'll try to use the attribute at the beginning of the declarator (as in C23).

Answer (score 0):

in my test, even base on the function without attribute, it stall can optimize code with command: **~/gcc11.1.0-install/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc test2.c -O3 -S**

```
main:
.LFB23:
        .cfi_startproc
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 29, -16
        .cfi_offset 30, -8
        mov     w0, 4
        mov     x29, sp
        bl      my_malloc
        adrp    x1, .LANCHOR0
        mov     w0, 0
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 16
        .cfi_restore 30
        .cfi_restore 29
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
        str     wzr, [x1, #:lo12:.LANCHOR0]
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE23:
        .size   main, .-main
```